# Personalizar a impressão php

Tags: php, html, css, impressão

Gostaria de editar essa view para imprimir os itens separados, cada item gerar uma impressão.
  Segue o Código:

```
                                       <?php

              include "QRCodeGenerator.class.php";

               function product_name($name)
                 {
                     return character_limiter($name, (isset($Settings->char_per_line) ? ($Settings->char_per_line-8) : 35));
                      }

                       if ($modal) {
                          echo '<div class="modal-dialog no-modal-header"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-body"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-2x">&times;</i></button>';
                        } else { ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?= $page_title . " " . lang("no") . " " . $inv->id; ?></title>
    <base href="<?= base_url() ?>"/>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?= $assets ?>images/icon.png"/>
    <link href="<?= $assets ?>bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        body { color: #000; }
        #wrapper { max-width: 480px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 20px; }
        .btn { border-radius: 0; margin-bottom: 5px; }
        .table { border-radius: 3px; }
        .table th { background: #f5f5f5; }
        .table th, .table td { vertical-align: middle !important; }
        h3 { margin: 5px 0; }

        @media print {
            .no-print { display: none; }
            #wrapper { max-width: 480px; width: 100%; min-width: 250px; margin: 0 auto; }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

                         <?php } ?>
                           <div id="wrapper">
<div id="receiptData">
<div class="no-print">
    <?php if ($message) { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
            <?= is_array($message) ? print_r($message, true) : $message; ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<div id="receipt-data">
    <div class="text-center">
            <?= $Settings->header; ?>
            <p>
            <?= lang('sale').' '.lang('no').': '.$inv->id; ?><br>
            <?= lang("date").': '.$this->tec->hrld($inv->date); ?>
            </p>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-center col-xs-6"><?=lang('description');?></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-xs-1"><?=lang('quantity');?></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-xs-2"><?=lang('price');?></th>
                    <th class="text-center col-xs-3"><?=lang('subtotal');?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            $tax_summary = array();
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                echo '<tr><td class="text-left">' . product_name($row->product_name) . '</td>';
                echo '<td class="text-center">' . $this->tec->formatNumber($row->quantity) . '</td>';
                echo '<td class="text-right">';

                if ($inv->total_discount != 0) {
                    $price_with_discount = $this->tec->formatMoney($row->net_unit_price + $this->tec->formatDecimal($row->item_discount / $row->quantity));
                    $pr_tax = $row->tax_method ?
                    $this->tec->formatDecimal((($price_with_discount) * $row->tax) / 100) :
                    $this->tec->formatDecimal((($price_with_discount) * $row->tax) / (100 + $row->tax));
                    echo '<del>' . $this->tec->formatMoney($price_with_discount+$pr_tax) . '</del> ';
                }

                echo $this->tec->formatMoney($row->net_unit_price + ($row->item_tax / $row->quantity)) . '</td><td class="text-right">' . $this->tec->formatMoney($row->subtotal) . '</td></tr>';
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"><?= lang("total"); ?></th>
                <th colspan="2" class="text-right"><?= $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->total + $inv->product_tax); ?></th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            if ($inv->order_tax != 0) {
                echo '<tr><th colspan="2">' . lang("order_tax") . '</th><th colspan="2" class="text-right">' . $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->order_tax) . '</th></tr>';
            }
            if ($inv->total_discount != 0) {
                echo '<tr><th colspan="2">' . lang("order_discount") . '</th><th colspan="2" class="text-right">' . $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->total_discount) . '</th></tr>';
            }

            if ($Settings->rounding) {
                $round_total = $this->tec->roundNumber($inv->grand_total, $Settings->rounding);
                $rounding = $this->tec->formatMoney($round_total - $inv->grand_total);
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"><?= lang("rounding"); ?></th>
                    <th colspan="2" class="text-right"><?= $rounding; ?></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"><?= lang("grand_total"); ?></th>
                    <th colspan="2" class="text-right"><?= $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->grand_total + $rounding); ?></th>
                </tr>
            <?php
            } else {
                $round_total = $inv->grand_total;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"><?= lang("grand_total"); ?></th>
                    <th colspan="2" class="text-right"><?= $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->grand_total); ?></th>
                </tr>
            <?php }
            if ($inv->paid < $round_total) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"><?= lang("paid_amount"); ?></th>
                    <th colspan="2" class="text-right"><?= $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->paid); ?></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2"><?= lang("due_amount"); ?></th>
                    <th colspan="2" class="text-right"><?= $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->grand_total - $inv->paid); ?></th>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <?php
        if ($payments) {
            echo '<table class="table table-striped table-condensed"><tbody>';
            foreach ($payments as $payment) {
                echo '<tr>';
                if ($payment->paid_by == 'cash' && $payment->pos_paid) {
                    echo '<td>' . lang("paid_by") . ': ' . lang($payment->paid_by) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . lang("amount") . ': ' . $this->tec->formatMoney($payment->pos_paid == 0 ? $payment->amount : $payment->pos_paid) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . lang("change") . ': ' . ($payment->pos_balance > 0 ? $this->tec->formatMoney($payment->pos_balance) : 0) . '</td>';
                }
                if (($payment->paid_by == 'CC' || $payment->paid_by == 'ppp' || $payment->paid_by == 'stripe') && $payment->cc_no) {
                    echo '<td>' . lang("paid_by") . ': ' . lang($payment->paid_by) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . lang("amount") . ': ' . $this->tec->formatMoney($payment->pos_paid) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . lang("no") . ': ' . 'xxxx xxxx xxxx ' . substr($payment->cc_no, -4) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . lang("name") . ': ' . $payment->cc_holder . '</td>';
                }
                if ($payment->paid_by == 'Cheque' && $payment->cheque_no) {
                    echo '<td>' . lang("paid_by") . ': ' . lang($payment->paid_by) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . lang("amount") . ': ' . $this->tec->formatMoney($payment->pos_paid) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . lang("cheque_no") . ': ' . $payment->cheque_no . '</td>';
                }
                if ($payment->paid_by == 'gift_card' && $payment->pos_paid) {
                    echo '<td>' . lang("paid_by") . ': ' . lang($payment->paid_by) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . lang("no") . ': ' . $payment->gc_no . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . lang("amount") . ': ' . $this->tec->formatMoney($payment->pos_paid) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . lang("balance") . ': ' . ($payment->pos_balance > 0 ? $this->tec->formatMoney($payment->pos_balance) : 0) . '</td>';
                }
                if ($payment->paid_by == 'other' && $payment->amount) {
                    echo '<td>' . lang("paid_by") . ': ' . lang($payment->paid_by) . '</td>';
                    echo '<td>' . lang("amount") . ': ' . $this->tec->formatMoney($payment->pos_paid == 0 ? $payment->amount : $payment->pos_paid) . '</td>';
                    echo $payment->note ? '</tr><td colspan="2">' . lang("payment_note") . ': ' . $payment->note . '</td>' : '';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo '</tbody></table>';

            $ex1 = new QRCodeGenerator('http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/consulta.aspx?tipoConsulta=completa&tipoConteudo=XbSeqxE8pl8=MobLanche_PDVPARATODOS.COM.BR');
            //echo "<img src=".$ex1->generate().">";

            echo '';
            echo $customer->endereco.''.$customer->numero.' '.$customer->complemento.'<br />'.$customer->cep.' '.$customer->bairro.' '.$customer->cidade.''.$customer->estado;
            echo '<br />'.$customer->name;
            echo ' '.$customer->phone.'  '.$customer->cf2;
        }

        ?>

        <?= $inv->note ? '<p class="text-center">' . $this->tec->decode_html($inv->note) . '</p>' : ''; ?>
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <?= $Settings->footer; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
                              <?php if ($modal) {
                                  echo '</div></div></div></div>';
                                   } else { ?>
                                      <div id="buttons" style="padding-top:10px; text-transform:uppercase;" class="no-print">
<hr>
<?php if ($message) { ?>
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
    <?= is_array($message) ? print_r($message, true) : $message; ?>
</div>
                                        <?php } ?>

<?php if ($Settings->java_applet) { ?>
    <span class="col-xs-12"><a class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onClick="printReceipt()"><?= lang("print"); ?></a></span>
    <span class="col-xs-12"><a class="btn btn-block btn-info" type="button" onClick="openCashDrawer()"><?= lang('open_cash_drawer'); ?></a></span>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <span class="pull-right col-xs-12">
    <a href="javascript:window.print()" id="web_print" class="btn btn-block btn-primary"
       onClick="window.print();return false;"><?= lang("web_print"); ?></a>
</span>
<?php } ?>
<span></span>

<span class="col-xs-12">
    <a class="btn btn-block btn-warning" href="<?= site_url('pos'); ?>">Voltar</a>
</span>
<?php if (!$Settings->java_applet) { ?>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="background:#F5F5F5; padding:10px;">
        <font size="-2">

        <font>
<?php } ?>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

                                           </div>

                                               </div>
                                                <canvas id="hidden_screenshot" style="display:none;">

                                                     </canvas>
                                                        <div class="canvas_con" style="display:none;"></div>
                                                         <script src="<?= $assets ?>plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                                                           <?php if ($Settings->java_applet) {

    function drawLine($Settings)
    {
        $size = $Settings->char_per_line;
        $new = '';
        for ($i = 1; $i < $size; $i++) {
            $new .= '-';
        }
        $new .= ' ';
        return $new;
    }

    function printLine($str, $Settings, $sep = ":", $space = NULL)
    {
        $size = $space ? $space : $Settings->char_per_line;
        $lenght = strlen($str);
        list($first, $second) = explode(":", $str, 2);
        $new = $first . ($sep == ":" ? $sep : '');
        for ($i = 1; $i < ($size - $lenght); $i++) {
            $new .= ' ';
        }
        $new .= ($sep != ":" ? $sep : '') . $second;
        return $new;
    }

    function printText($text, $Settings)
    {
        $size = $Settings->char_per_line;
        $new = wordwrap($text, $size, "\\n");
        return $new;
    }

    function taxLine($name, $code, $qty, $amt, $tax)
    {
        return printLine(printLine(printLine(printLine($name . ':' . $code, '', 18) . ':' . $qty, '', 25) . ':' . $amt, '', 35) . ':' . $tax, ' ');
    }

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= $assets ?>plugins/qz/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?= $assets ?>plugins/qz/qz-functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        deployQZ('themes/<?=$Settings->theme?>/assets/plugins/qz/qz-print.jar', '<?= $assets ?>plugins/qz/qz-print_jnlp.jnlp');
        usePrinter("<?= $Settings->receipt_printer; ?>");
        <?php /*$image = $this->tec->save_barcode($inv->reference_no);*/ ?>
        function printReceipt() {
            //var barcode = 'data:image/png;base64,<?php /*echo $image;*/ ?>';
            receipt = "";
            receipt += chr(27) + chr(69) + "\r" + chr(27) + "\x61" + "\x31\r";
            receipt += "<?= printText(strip_tags(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $Settings->header)), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += " \x1B\x45\x0A\r ";
            receipt += "<?=drawLine($Settings);?>\r\n";
            //receipt += "<?php // if($Settings->invoice_view == 1) { echo lang('tax_invoice'); } ?>\r\n";
            //receipt += "<?php // if($Settings->invoice_view == 1) { echo drawLine(); } ?>\r\n";
            receipt += "\x1B\x61\x30";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("sale_no") . ": " . $inv->id, $Settings) ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("sales_person") . ": " . $created_by->first_name." ".$created_by->last_name, $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("customer") . ": " . $inv->customer_name, $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("date") . ": " . $this->tec->hrld($inv->date), $Settings); ?>" + "\n\n";
            receipt += "<?php $r = 1;
        foreach ($rows as $row): ?>";
            receipt += "<?= "#" . $r ." "; ?>";
            receipt += "<?= product_name(addslashes($row->product_name)); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine($this->tec->formatNumber($row->quantity)."x".$this->tec->formatMoney($row->net_unit_price+($row->item_tax/$row->quantity)) . ":  ". $this->tec->formatMoney($row->subtotal), $Settings, ' ') . ""; ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?php $r++;
        endforeach; ?>";
            receipt += "\x1B\x61\x31";
            receipt += "<?=drawLine($Settings);?>\r\n";
            receipt += "\x1B\x61\x30";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("total") . ": " . $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->total+$inv->product_tax), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            <?php if ($inv->order_tax != 0) { ?>
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("tax") . ": " . $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->order_tax), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($inv->total_discount != 0) { ?>
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("discount") . ": " . $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->total_discount), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if($Settings->rounding) { ?>
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("rounding") . ": " . $rounding, $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("grand_total") . ": " . $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->grand_total + $rounding), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            <?php } else { ?>
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("grand_total") . ": " . $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->grand_total), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if($inv->paid < $inv->grand_total) { ?>
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("paid_amount") . ": " . $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->paid), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("due_amount") . ": " . $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->grand_total-$inv->paid), $Settings); ?>" + "\n\n";
            <?php } ?>
            <?php
            if($payments) {
                foreach($payments as $payment) {
                    if ($payment->paid_by == 'cash' && $payment->pos_paid) { ?>
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("paid_by") . ": " . lang($payment->paid_by), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("amount") . ": " . $this->tec->formatMoney($payment->pos_paid), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("change") . ": " . ($payment->pos_balance > 0 ? $this->tec->formatMoney($payment->pos_balance) : 0), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            <?php } if (($payment->paid_by == 'CC' || $payment->paid_by == 'ppp' || $payment->paid_by == 'stripe') && $payment->cc_no) { ?>
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("paid_by") . ": " . lang($payment->paid_by), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("amount") . ": " . $this->tec->formatMoney($payment->pos_paid), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("card_no") . ": xxxx xxxx xxxx " . substr($payment->cc_no, -4), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            <?php  } if ($payment->paid_by == 'gift_card') { ?>
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("paid_by") . ": " . lang($payment->paid_by), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("amount") . ": " . $this->tec->formatMoney($payment->pos_paid), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("card_no") . ": " . $payment->gc_no, $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            <?php } if ($payment->paid_by == 'Cheque' && $payment->cheque_no) { ?>
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("paid_by") . ": " . lang($payment->paid_by), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("amount") . ": " . $this->tec->formatMoney($payment->pos_paid), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("cheque_no") . ": " . $payment->cheque_no, $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            <?php if ($payment->paid_by == 'other' && $payment->amount) { ?>
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("paid_by") . ": " . lang($payment->paid_by), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("amount") . ": " . $this->tec->formatMoney($payment->amount), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= printText(lang("payment_note") . ": " . $payment->note, $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            <?php }
        }

    }
                                                                   }

                                                            /* if($Settings->invoice_view == 1) {
                                                                      if(!empty($tax_summary)) {
                                                                           ?>
            receipt += "\n" + "<?= lang('tax_summary'); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?= taxLine(lang('name'),lang('code'),lang('qty'),lang('tax_excl'),lang('tax_amt')); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?php foreach ($tax_summary as $summary): ?>";
            receipt += "<?= taxLine($summary['name'],$summary['code'],$this->tec->formatNumber($summary['items']),$this->tec->formatMoney($summary['amt']),$this->tec->formatMoney($summary['tax'])); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "<?php endforeach; ?>";
            receipt += "<?= printLine(lang("total_tax_amount") . ":" . $this->tec->formatMoney($inv->product_tax)); ?>" + "\n";
            <?php
                }
            } */
            ?>
            receipt += "\x1B\x61\x31";
            <?php if ($inv->note) { ?>
            receipt += "<?= printText(strip_tags(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $this->tec->decode_html($inv->note))), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            <?php } ?>
            receipt += "<?= printText(strip_tags(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ', $Settings->footer)), $Settings); ?>" + "\n";
            receipt += "\x1B\x61\x30";
            <?php if(isset($Settings->cash_drawer_cose)) { ?>
            print(receipt, '', '<?=$Settings->cash_drawer_cose;?>');
            <?php } else { ?>
            print(receipt, '', '');
            <?php } ?>

                                                                                    }

                                                                                     </script>
                                                                                            <?php } ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#email').click(function () {
                    var email = prompt("<?= lang("email_address"); ?>", "<?= $customer->email; ?>");
                    if (email != null) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "post",
                            url: "<?= site_url('pos/email_receipt') ?>",
                            data: {<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>: "<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>", email: email, id: <?= $inv->id; ?>},
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(data.msg);
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert('<?= lang('ajax_request_failed'); ?>');
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });
                                                                                             <?php if (!$Settings->java_applet && !$noprint) { ?>
                                                                                                  $(window).load(function () {
                                                                                                        window.print();
                                                                                                                 });
                                                                                                                          <?php } ?>
                                                                                                                                        </script>
                                                                                                                                            </body>
                                                                                                                                                        </html>
                                                                                                                                                             <?php } ?>
```